Is it possible to use `std::index_sequence` in a concept?
Say you wanted to define a concept that checks that all alternatives of a variant are convertible to int. You could do it like so:
#include <concepts>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>
#include <variant>

template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToInt = std::convertible_to<T, int>;

template <typename T>
concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = []<auto... i>(std::index_sequence<i...>){
    return (ConvertibleToInt<std::variant_alternative_t<i, T>> && ...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<T>>{});

If the constraint fails, you get a relatively descriptive error (for C++ standards):
static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);

<source>:12:15: error: static assertion failed
   12 | static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:12:15: note: because 'std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>' (aka 'variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>') does not satisfy 'AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt'
<source>:8:43: note: because '[]<auto ...i>(std::index_sequence<i...>) {
    return (ConvertibleToInt<std::variant_alternative_t<i, variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t> > > && ...);
}(std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t> > >{})' evaluated to false
    8 | concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = []<auto... i>(std::index_sequence<i...>){
      |                                           ^
1 error generated.

However, the error message doesn't show which of the alternatives failed the constraint. For that to happen, AFAIK you'd need to use only concepts.
I was unable to find a way to have a parameter pack from 0 to std::variant_size_v, other than writing it manually like so:
template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToInt = std::convertible_to<T, int>;

template <typename T, auto... i>
concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToIntImpl = (ConvertibleToInt<std::variant_alternative_t<i, T>> && ...);

template <typename T>
concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = AllAlternativesConvertibleToIntImpl<T, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>;

static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);

Note that now the error message says alternative #4 does not satisfy the constraint:
<source>:24:15: error: static assertion failed
   24 | static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:24:15: note: because 'std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>' (aka 'variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>') does not satisfy 'AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt'
<source>:22:43: note: because 'AllAlternativesConvertibleToIntImpl<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>' evaluated to false
   22 | concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = AllAlternativesConvertibleToIntImpl<T, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4>;
      |                                           ^
<source>:19:48: note: because 'std::variant_alternative_t<4, variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>' (aka 'std::nullptr_t') does not satisfy 'ConvertibleToInt'
   19 | concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToIntImpl = (ConvertibleToInt<std::variant_alternative_t<i, T>> && ...);
      |                                                ^
<source>:16:28: note: because 'std::convertible_to<std::nullptr_t, int>' evaluated to false
   16 | concept ConvertibleToInt = std::convertible_to<T, int>;
      |                            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/concepts:79:30: note: because 'is_convertible_v<std::nullptr_t, int>' evaluated to false
   79 |     concept convertible_to = is_convertible_v<_From, _To>
      |                              ^
1 error generated.

Is it possible to do this without writing the parameter pack manually?

I don't think you can, but if you are just concerned about the error message, something like this may work.

implementation can be significantly simpler: https://godbolt.org/z/5GsxenGbT
but compiler wouldn't tell what exactly caused constraint to fail

@Gene Your implementation assumes T is default constructible. Also getting the helpful error message is the whole point of this question.

@Weijun Zhou -- I still like my implementation Though compiler doesn't report the exact type, on the positive side it works not just for variant but for every similar type. Default constructible requirement can be easily fixed by using pointers, https://godbolt.org/z/1a6Yr48G7

Weijun Zhou's comment made me realize you can use a function to check which of the alternatives fails the constraint (if any).
Based on that, I came up with this:
#include <algorithm>
#include <variant>

template <typename T>
concept ConvertibleToInt = std::convertible_to<T, int>;

template <typename T>
consteval auto get_failing_index()
{
    return []<auto... i>(std::index_sequence<i...>){
        return std::min({ -1uz, (!ConvertibleToInt<std::variant_alternative_t<i, T>> ? i : -1uz)... });
    }(std::make_index_sequence<std::variant_size_v<T>>{});
}

template <auto i, typename T, typename Default>
struct GuardedVariantAlternativeHelper
{
    using Type = std::variant_alternative_t<i, T>;
};

template <typename T, typename Default>
struct GuardedVariantAlternativeHelper<-1uz, T, Default>
{
    using Type = Default;
};

template <auto i, typename T, typename Default>
using GuardedVariantAlternative = GuardedVariantAlternativeHelper<i, T, Default>::Type;

template <typename T, std::size_t i>
concept AlternativeConvertibleToInt = ConvertibleToInt<GuardedVariantAlternative<i, T, int>>;

template <typename T>
concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = AlternativeConvertibleToInt<T, get_failing_index<T>()>;

static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<>>);
static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double>>);
static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);

Which results in:
<source>:38:15: error: static assertion failed
   38 | static_assert(AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>>);
      |               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:38:15: note: because 'std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>' (aka 'variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>') does not satisfy 'AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt'
<source>:34:43: note: because 'AlternativeConvertibleToInt<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>, get_failing_index<std::variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t> >()>' evaluated to false
   34 | concept AllAlternativesConvertibleToInt = AlternativeConvertibleToInt<T, get_failing_index<T>()>;
      |                                           ^
<source>:31:39: note: because 'GuardedVariantAlternative<4UL, variant<char, int, float, double, std::nullptr_t>, int>' (aka 'std::nullptr_t') does not satisfy 'ConvertibleToInt'
   31 | concept AlternativeConvertibleToInt = ConvertibleToInt<GuardedVariantAlternative<i, T, int>>;
      |                                       ^
<source>:5:28: note: because 'std::convertible_to<std::nullptr_t, int>' evaluated to false
    5 | concept ConvertibleToInt = std::convertible_to<T, int>;
      |                            ^
/opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-14.2.0/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/14.2.0/../../../../include/c++/14.2.0/concepts:79:30: note: because 'is_convertible_v<std::nullptr_t, int>' evaluated to false
   79 |     concept convertible_to = is_convertible_v<_From, _To>
      |                              ^
1 error generated.

And is pretty much what I wanted.

I knew my implementation could be simplified but I didn't have more time to work on it. You have my upvote.
